# How to connect Microsoft Communicator with email address of another domain set up with domains.live.com

Tags: communicator

I manage my emails of my domain on Microsoft Live (domains.live.com). I want to know how I can configure email address on Microsoft Communicator to enable chatting feature.

I have tried connecting using Advanced connection settings in Tools -> Options -> Advanced Settings

When I choose manual configuration what should I provide on:
• Internal Server Name or IP address
• External Server Name or IP address
• Connect using  TCP or TLS

Comment: What version of communicator?

Comment: microsoft office communicator 2007 R2 Version: 3.5.6907.268

Comment: I don't believe Communicator 2007 is going to be able to do this.  Have you tried each option with the correct information for your setup?

Comment: i dont know what options should i use on this i belive basic windows live setting will work but i dont know what that settings is.. Because the mail interface that windows provide is the same windows live mail

Comment: What that statement does not make sense.  You don't know your internal and external IP addresses?

Comment: Sorry am new to this.. my domain is accountsworld.in

Comment: @wanthkumarKS - Why would I need to know that information?  Since you don't have an internal server, you would fill out the information for the external server, and select TCP or TLS based on your account's setting.

Comment: ok ill try to find it out. thank you for your time